# igraph python remove border

Tags: python, igraph

I am trying to remove the border of node vertices in igraph, but I can't find a way. I found many references on google that in R, you can change this attribute:

```
vertex.frame.color
```

but in igraph for python, I could not find a way. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look into the [documentation](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Graph-class.html#__plot__), it's done in basically the same way. Example:

```
import igraph
g = igraph.Graph([(0,1), (0,2), (2,1)])
igraph.plot(g, vertex_frame_color='red')
```

Comment: What is the correct value to remove the border? In your example you make it red. This can make the border the same colour as the background, however when nodes overlap the border is still visible. A `None` gives the default and `""` gives an error message.

Comment: This solution gives the frame the same color as the vertex face (i.e. red in this example). I can't test right now, but you can try to set the frame to transparent. According to the documentation `"rgba(0%, 0%, 0%, 0%)"` should work (see http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.drawing.colors-module.html#color_name_to_rgba). Otherwise you can experiment with setting the frame width to zero, as in `igraph.plot(g, vertex_frame_width=0)`.